# Flyway: how to execute a function after each migration

Tags: flyway

I'm working on a project where we use flyway to upgrade our DB schema.

I'm using `flyway` through the `gradle` plugin.

I need to execute a specific function every time a migration ends: we don't want to add the call to every migration manually.

The script will be exactly the same every time, so repeatable migration is a no go (it will be executed again only when the hash of the script changes).

I've tried to use sql callbacks, but they seem not working properly with the gradle plugin: if I run flyway on command line the callback sql is executed correctly (all migrations and callback are in sql dir within flyway distro) while it's not executed in gradle (migrations and callbacks are in directory `src/main/db/migration` set as `filesystem:src/main/db/migration` in flyway gradle configuration).

Can anyone help with the correct `gradle` plugin configuration for `flyway` or maybe suggest an alternative solution?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `afterMigrate` callback. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks

Comment: Hi Axel, and thanks for the reply. Probably I didn't explain correctly what I tried, but my issue is exactly with afterMigrate just in gradle (command line works fine). Docs are not clear about files position for gradle task.

Comment: SQL callbacks and migrations are loaded via the exact same mechanism. Also (obviously) make sure you are on the latest version of Flyway to avoid hitting any potential old issue that may have long been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: I've tried to run it on FlyWay 5.2.4 with no joy. Can you please confirm that callback sqls should be picked up from any location set in the `locations` configuration of the gradle plugin, please?

Comment: Confirmed. They are loaded along with the SQL migrations.